# form validation in PHP using preg_match

Tags: php, validation

Hi I am trying to validate a simple HTML form. Here is my HTML code-

```
<HTML>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="password.php">
        User ID<input type="text" name="user" id="user" required/><br/>
        Password<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value"Login Here">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The password must contain only digits. My password.php is-

```
<?php
    $name=$_GET['user'];
    $pass=$_GET['pass'];

    $strlen1= strlen($name);
    $strlen2= strlen($pass);

    $regex= "/^[789][0-9]{9}$/";   // my password should contain digits only.

    if($strlen1==0 | $strlen2==0)   
        {
            echo 'Username or password field is empty'.'<br/>';
        }

    else if($name==$pass)
        {
            echo 'Go for a better password'.'<br/>';
        }

    else if(!preg_match($regex,$pass))
        {
            echo 'password is invalid'.'<br/>';
        }

    else
        {
            echo 'You have successfully logged in'.'<br/>';
        }

    ?>
```

On running the script even when I enter the valid password like-"123456" the message says- "password is invalid".
Please let me know the mistake in above code.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Your regex `^[789][0-9]{9}$` requires the password to start with `7`, `8` or `9` followed by exactly 9 digits. Change it to `^\d+$` to accept any amount of digits or such as `^\d{6,}$` for at least 6 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password should begin with any of 7, 8, 9 and followed by 9 digits

```
$regex= "/^[789][0-9]{9}$/";
```

to filter digits only replace it with:

```
$regex="/^\d+$/";
```